# Listview with complex item having a microsecond delay when loading

Tags: android, jquery, listview

I've spent two days trying to find a solution for this problem and couldn't find it anywhere. My problem is: I have a List View in which each item has 4 text views and an ImageView. I'm fetching data from a website using Volley. The data loads normally and when a I scroll down everything works perfectly. The problem is when I scroll back. When I'm scrolling back the images and textviews have a 0.5 delay to appear (First I see the picture of the last item) and then the content is shown. I've already tried recyclerview and listview with viewholder. This "flick" persists in both solutions.

```
public class BigCategoryListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private Context context;
    private String[] smallCatsList;
    private News news;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;

    static class myViewHolder{
    TextView smallCatName;
    RelativeLayout spinner;
    ImageView newsImageView;
    TextView newsTitle;
    TextView newsContent;


}

public BigCategoryListViewAdapter(Context context, String[] smallCatsList){
    this.context = context;
    this.smallCatsList = smallCatsList;
    this.imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    if(!this.imageLoader.isInited()) {  this.imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));}
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return smallCatsList.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return smallCatsList[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {return 0;} //modificar aqui



@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final myViewHolder mvh;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);



    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bigcat_listview,null);

    mvh = new myViewHolder();

    mvh.smallCatName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bigcat_viewpager_smallcat);
    mvh.spinner = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    mvh.newsImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bigcat_viewpager_imageView);
    mvh.newsTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bigcat_viewpager_news_title);
    mvh.newsContent = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bigcat_viewpager_content);
    convertView.setTag(mvh);


    mvh.smallCatName.setText(smallCatsList[position]);

    JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
    try{
        params.put("slug",smallCatsList[position]);
        params.put("startIndex", 0);
        params.put("endIndex", 0);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(getClass().toString(), "Error setting params for communication with server");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Volley volley = Volley.getVolley(context);
    volley.runRequest(Request.Method.POST, VolleyConstants.PROD_URL + VolleyConstants.NEWS_FETCH_ROUTE,
        params, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        //---------------------Volley------------------//

    @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            JSONArray responseArr = null;
            try {
                responseArr = response.getJSONArray("newsArr");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < responseArr.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    JSONObject object = responseArr.getJSONObject(i);
                    String photoURLString = object.getString("photo");
                    String titleString = object.getString("title");
                    String publisherString = object.getString("publisher");
                    String dateString = object.getJSONObject("date").getString("date");
                    String contentString = object.getString("contents");
                    String urlString = object.getString("url");

                    news = new News(photoURLString, titleString, publisherString, dateString, contentString,urlString);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    news = new News("Unknown", "Unknown", "Unknown", "Unknown", "Unknown","Unknown");
                }




            }
            //tv2.setText(news.getNewsDate());

            mvh.newsContent.setText(news.getNewsContent());
            mvh.newsTitle.setText(news.getNewsHead());

            //---------------------Image Loading------------------//
            try {
                URL url = new URL(news.getNewsPic());
                imageLoader.loadImage(news.getNewsPic(), new ImageLoadingListener() {
                @Override
                    public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {

                    }

                @Override
                    public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {

                    }

                @Override
                    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                        mvh.newsImageView.setImageBitmap(loadedImage);
                        mvh.spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                @Override
                    public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {


                    }
                });
            }catch(Exception e){
                mvh.newsImageView.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.nopic));
                mvh.spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }


        }
    }, new CustomErrorListener("ERROR"));

    return convertView;
}
```

This is my adapter. My question is if there is a way to remove this delay to show the content? Or is my problem with network or the listview itself?
I just wanna load all the content for once and then the user can scroll up and down without having to refresh the content everytime.

Answer (score 0):

You're loading the content every time getView is called, that's why it's loading like that. Separate the Volley request from the getView, it should be outside of the adapter entirely, not called upon every load of every piece of the list. You have your News Objects, you can pass an ArrayList to the adapter and fill it from there, that will fix your loading issue. Also, you're calling volley in the Main thread instead of a new thread, you should separate the two, and populate the ListView adapter upon completion of the content being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

One, the ViewHolder pattern example should be something more like this:

```
if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bigcat_listview,null);

    mvh = new myViewHolder();
    //... rest of your code
} else {
    mvh = (myViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    //... rest of your code
}
```

Second, the major Volley loading stuff should not be in the adapter, but processed elsewhere beforehand then passed in. This [example](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/) should help you out a lot.